# Datepicker not triggering after the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am facing some issues with the JQuery Datepicker.

As you can see in my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2vtercs1/11/ i created a table and i added in the second column a datepicker, and it's working fine.

My target is to be able to clone the first row and add it to the bottom of the table. The cloning part is working fine, but the second datepicker is not triggering. I tried to change the class of the second datepicker to be "datepicker2", and i initiate it in the script from the beginning

`$( function() {
    $( ".datepicker2" ).datepicker();
 } );`

but with no success. can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a datepicker to an element, it adds the class `hasDatepicker` to that element so as to know that it already has a datepicker, and not add another one.

When you clone the element, the element still has that class, but no datepicker.
You have to either call the jQuery UI datepicker `destroy` method, or just remove the class, to be able to add a datepicker

$(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker();
});

```
$(document).on('click', '.clone', function() {
  var currRow = $(this).closest('tr');
  var clone   = currRow.clone(false);

  clone.prop('id', 'row' + ($(".datepicker").length + 1));
  currRow.after(clone);

  $('.datepicker').removeClass('hasDatepicker').removeAttr('id').datepicker();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/2vtercs1/15/)

Comment: In your fiddle, if he select any date that will reflect only in first row.

Comment: Thank you @adeneo.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to clone the datepicker, you have `destroy` the reference of the old datepicker and need to remove the `id` attribute and then need to trigger it.

```
 $(".clone").on('click', function(){
    var trow = $("table tr#row1").clone(true);
    trow.attr( 'id', function() { return this.id + Math.random(); });
    trow.find('input.datepicker').datepicker("destroy").removeAttr('id').datepicker();
    trow.appendTo("table");
  })
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/2vtercs1/14/)